Spring security jwt filter
in spring security if i set the security context is all the downstream filler of authentication will stell authenticate user or not
i try to implement spring security with jwt and form authentication i wont to understand the logic of jwt fillter and how the request will process this filter chain
`
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver;

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(
        JwtService jwtService,
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver
    ) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.handlerExceptionResolver = handlerExceptionResolver;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
        @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
        @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        try {
            final String jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
            final String userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);

            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            if (userEmail != null && authentication == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);

                if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new 
                     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails,
                            null,
                            userDetails.getAuthorities()
                    );

                    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
            }

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, null, exception);
        }
    }
}`


Have you written above code by yourself? If yes, you already know the logic. If no, I suggest you to go through a simpler article first. You can google it.
